# I have ambiguous routes or need to supply additional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

---

### in `config/routes.rb`

```
map.resources :projects do |project|
  project.resource :privacy
  end
end
```

---

### in `models/project.rb`

```
belongs_to :privacy
```

---

### in models/privacy.rb

```
has_one :project
```

---

### in show.html.haml

```
= change_privacy_button(@project)
```

---

### in an accessible helper

```
  def change_privacy_button(project)
      button_builder("24gray/edit.png", "Edit Privacy Settings", edit_project_privacy_path(project), "change_privacy_settings")
  end
```

---

This is giving me the following error:

```
Couldn't find Privacy without an ID (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

The error occurs on:

```
http://localhost:3000/projects/:id/privacy/edit
```

Rake routes tells me to use:

```
edit_project_privacy GET
/projects/:project_id/privacy/edit(.:format)
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"privacies"}
```

In the debugger, I can summon:

```
(rdb:1) project
#<Project id: 1...

(rdb:1) project
#<Project id: 1...

(rdb:1) project.privacy
#<Privacy id: 1...

(rdb:1) edit_project_privacy_path
ActionController::RoutingError Exception: edit_project_privacy_url failed to generate from {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"privacies"} - you may have ambiguous routes, or you may need to supply additional parameters for this route.  content_url has the following required parameters: ["projects", :project_id, "privacy", "edit"] - are they all satisfied?
```

Your thoughts? Thanks! PS, all of the following have also failed:

```
edit_project_privacy_path(project, project.privacy)

edit_project_privacy_path(project.id, project.privacy)

edit_project_privacy_path(project.privacy_id, project.privacy)

edit_project_privacy_path(project.privacy_id)

edit_project_privacy_path(project.privacy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
edit_project_privacy_path(:project_id => project.id)
```

or

```
edit_project_privacy_path(project.privacy, project)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that @project isn't being set, and is defaulting to nil, in your view.

Instance variables initialize themselves to nil rather than reporting that they've never been set.

What is your ActiveResource or ApplicationController subclass called?